# Communication with client and server using sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, networkstream

So I have written the code so that I can communicate with server and client.

- The first question is how does the server identify that its communicating with an actual client, not someone else who's using the port, I've heard that browsers verify with servers using SHA hashing.
- Second question is about the best way to send and receive data in variables, and also identifying which is which, because the current method of splitting data doesn't seem very elegant.

Server side code to receive and send data:

```
NetworkStream NetStream1 = TCPSocket.GetStream();                       
NetStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
ReceivedData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer);
string[] splitter = ReceivedData.Split('-');
Variable1 = splitter[0];
Variable2 = splitter[1];
//send response
SendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ResultINT1+"-"+ResultINT2);
NetStream.Write(SendBuffer, 0, SendBuffer.Length);
NetStream.Flush();
```

Client code to send and receive

```
NetworkStream SendStream = ClientSocket.GetStream();
byte[] SendBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(V1+"-"+V2);
SendStream.Write(SendBuffer, 0, SendBuffer.Length);
SendStream.Flush();
//response
SendStream.Read(RecieveBuffer, 0, RecieveBuffer.Length);
string ResultString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(RecieveBuffer);
string[] splitted = ResultString.Split('-');
int R1 = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[0]);
int R2 = Convert.ToInt16(splitted[1]);
```

Comment: Your code is broken. You don't know how many bytes have been placed in `ReceiveBuffer` (You're ignoring the return value from `Read` which would tell you), so it's unsafe to convert the entire buffer into a string. There's no guarantee that calls of `Write` at one end are matched with calls to `Read` at the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question concerns authentication which is a huge subject and has many possible implementations although I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "someone else who's using the port". Your server should always be on the same port - that is how the client identifies a service.

Regarding your second question there are again many possibilities but I would suggest that the simplest for a beginner would be using **XmlSerializer** and a simple message envelope.

1. Create an XmlSerializable class either just using simple public properties or perhaps decorating with XmlElementAttribute, XmlRootAttribute etc.
2. Serialize to a MemoryStream
3. Write the bytes from the memory stream wrapped in an envelope (see later)
4. Receive a **complete** envelope into a byte array.
5. construct a MemoryStream from the byte array
6. Use XmlSerializer to reconstruct a copy of your original object.

The envelope is critical. The simplest one is just the binary length of the serialized object. Most protocols will typically extend that with CRC to handle possible corruption but since Ethernet uses a strong CRC and TCP is a reliable transport (albeit with a weak CRC) that is usually overkill. The key point that beginners miss is that TCP is a streaming protocol not a message based protocol thus it is perfectly possible for a sender to make a single write of say 1000 bytes and yet the receiver receives this as a number of smaller chunks. This is why you need some way to detect the end of a message such as using a length and why the receiver needs to accumulate received chunks until a complete message (and possibly part of the next) is received and can be deserialized.

This may seem complicated but unfortunately, at the TCP level, it doesn't get any simpler than that :(

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I tried sending a file stream, but it was way slower and unreliable compared to using http

Answer (score 2):

1. Provide some authentication mechanism
2. Use some serializer.

Comment: Hmm, I assume your talking about object serialization. I'm looking into it right now. Also can you point me to some authentication methods that will work for my model?

Comment: You could do naive things like expect a predefined token by the client (if not ok close communication) or do advanced things like those descripted in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14155/An-Asynchronous-Socket-Server-and-Client

Answer (score 0):

> The first question is how does the server identify that its communicating with an actual client, not someone else who's using the port, I've heard that browsers verify with servers using SHA hashing.

The server can identify different client by their IP addresses. See `StreamReader.ReadToEnd`

> Second question is about the best way to send and receive data in variables, and also identifying which is which, because the current method of splitting data doesn't seem very elegant.

It depends on your protocol architecture, but a portable way to exchange values on network is to keep them in text format (this way no problem of endianness, type size...).

Said that, be careful of your variable separator : a `'-'` might be difficult to use with negative numbers, `' '` or `';'` are more common.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define a communication protocol of some kind - a text-based protocol would be most straightforward to begin with - you can then read and write the "commands" each on a separate line.

First, there would be a "handshake", where the client would send something like "HELLO my-awesome-protocol-v1\n" and the server would respond similarly. This way you will be sure that the other person is a client, who understands the protocol or you can close a connection, which does not implement the protocol.

Then there could be some way of sending the values of variables with commands like "VAR variableName 123.45\n". You can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol and see http://www.ncftp.com/libncftp/doc/ftp_overview.html for inspiration.